# 3D Bin Packing Using Pulp

Tags: python, pulp, bin-packing

I am trying to solve the 3D bin packing problem which is NP-hard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) using linear programming optimizer. I have just started with PuLP and facing some issues. I have added in detail my constraints, code, output and the help I am in need of.

CONSTRAINTS:

The objective function is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Zyz.png) and I wish to model the following constraints 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ZAP.png) where [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch4Aw.png)

PYTHON CODE:

```
     from pulp import *

        #Variable Decleration
        prob = LpProblem('BinPacking', LpMinimize)

        ps = [LpVariable("p{0}{1}".format(i + 1, j + 1), cat="Binary")
              for i in range(parcel.parcels) for j in range(parcel.containers)]
        print(ps)

        us = [LpVariable("u{0}".format(j + 1), cat="Binary") for j in range(parcel.containers)]
        print(us)
    #location of left bottom (x,y,z)
        xs = [LpVariable("x{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]        

        ys = [LpVariable("y{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]    

        zs = [LpVariable("z{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]

        rs = [LpVariable("r{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]       

        ss = [LpVariable("s{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]   

        ts = [LpVariable("t{0}".format(i+1), cat="Integer") for i in range(parcel.parcels)]

    #for the overlapping constraint
        xik = [LpVariable("xik", cat="Binary")]
        yik = [LpVariable("yik", cat="Binary")]
        zik = [LpVariable("zik", cat="Binary")]
        xki = [LpVariable("xki", cat="Binary")]
        yki = [LpVariable("yki", cat="Binary")]
        zki = [LpVariable("zki", cat="Binary")]

    #orientation
        a = ["1", "2", "3"]
        b = ["1", "2", "3"]
        os = [LpVariable("o{0}{1}".format(j, k), cat="Binary")for j in a for k in b]
    print(os)     


# Objective function

     t = lpSum([us[i] * parcel.conVolume[i] for i in range(parcel.containers)]) - sum(parcel.parVolume)
        prob += t
        print(t)


# Dimension Constraint
     a = []
        for j in range(parcel.parcels):
            b = rs[j] - xs[j]
            a.append(b)
            a[j] = parcel.parLength[j]
        print(a)
        for j in range(parcel.parcels):
            u = ps[j * parcel.containers: (j + 1) * parcel.containers]
            condition1 = sum([u1 * w for u1, w in zip(u, parcel.conLength)])
            #print(rs[j])
            t = rs[j] <= condition1
            prob += t
            print(t)

# Overlapping Constraint
    for i in range(parcel.parcels):
        if rs[i - 1] <= xs[i]:
            xik = 1
            xki = 0
        elif xs[i] < rs[i + 1]:
            xik = 0
            xki = 1
    print(xik, xki)

    for i in range(parcel.parcels):
        # for k in range(parcel.parcels):
        # u = bs[i * parcel.containers: (i + 1) * parcel.containers]
        if ss[i - 1] <= ys[i]:
            yik = 1
            yki = 0
        elif ss[i] < ys[i - 1]:
            yik = 0
            yki = 1
    print(yik, yki)

    for i in range(parcel.parcels):
        # for k in range(parcel.parcels):
        # u = bs[i * parcel.containers: (i + 1) * parcel.containers]
        if ts[i - 1] <= zs[i]:
            zik = 1
            zki = 0
        elif ts[i] < zs[i - 1]:
            zik = 0
            zki = 1
    print(zik, zki)

    li = []
    for j in range(parcel.parcels):
        u = ps[j * parcel.containers: (j + 1) * parcel.containers]
        # print(u)
        li.append(u)
    # print(li)

    r = []
    for i in range(parcel.containers):
        z = [x[i] for x in li]
        r.append(z)

    for i in range(0, len(r)):
        for j in range(0, len(r[i])):
            if (j == len(r[i]) - 1):
                s = r[i][-1] + r[i][0]
            else:
                s = r[i][j] + r[i][j + 1]
            # print(s)
            t = xik + xki + yik + yki + zik + zki >= s - 1
            prob += t
            print(t)

    for i in range(parcel.containers):
        for j in range(parcel.parcels):
            a = rs[j - 1] <= xs[j] + (1 - xik) * parcel.conLength[i]
            b = xs[j] + 1 <= rs[j-1] + (xik * parcel.conLength[i])
            c = ss[j - 1] <= ys[j] + (1 - yik) * parcel.conWidth[i]
            d = ys[j] + 1 <= ss[j-1] + (yik * parcel.conWidth[i])
            e = ts[j - 1] <= zs[j] + (1 - zik) * parcel.conHeight[i]
            f = zs[j] + 1 <= ts[j-1] + (zik * parcel.conHeight[i])

            prob += a, b
            prob += c, d
            prob += e, f
            print(a, b, c, d, e, f)

 #

    Orientation Constraint  

    for i in range(parcel.parcels):
     p = (rs[i] - xs[i]) == ((os[0] * parcel.parLength[i])+(os[1] * parcel.parWidth[i])+(os[2]*parcel.parHeight[i]))
          q = (ss[i] - ys[i]) == ((os[3] * parcel.parLength[i]) + (os[4] * parcel.parWidth[i]) + (os[5] * parcel.parHeight[i]))
                r = (ts[i] - zs[i]) == ((os[6] * parcel.parLength[i])+(os[7] * parcel.parWidth[i])+(os[8]*parcel.parHeight[i]))
                prob += q
                prob += p, r
                print(p)
                print(q)
                print(r)

        # Output
            o11 = 0.0
            o12 = 0.0
            o13 = 0.0
            o21 = 0.0
            o22 = 0.0
            o23 = 0.0
            p11 = 1.0
            p12 = 0.0
            p21 = 1.0
            p22 = 0.0
            p31 = 1.0
            p32 = 0.0
            r1 = 0.0
            r2 = 0.0
            r3 = 0.0
            s1 = 0.0
            s2 = 0.0
            s3 = 0.0
            t1 = 0.0
            t2 = 0.0
            t3 = 0.0
            u1 = 1.0
            u2 = 0.0
            x1 = 0.0
            x2 = 0.0
            x3 = 0.0
            y1 = 0.0
            y2 = 0.0
            y3 = 0.0
            z1 = 0.0
            z2 = 0.0
            z3 = 0.0
```

QUESTIONS/HELP:

1. All the output values are 0. I am not sure if there is some issue in my constraints definition. Can someone help check my code?

THANKS!

Comment: You can only have 1 objective function, and that is the first prob += t you are doing, which looks more like a constraint than an objective

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So how do I change it? Should I just put that outside the for loop?

Comment: # Objective function
    for j in range(parcel.containers):
        u = us[j * parcel.containers: (j+1) * parcel.containers]
        vol = (sum([u1 * v for u1, v in zip(u, parcel.conVolume)]) - sum(parcel.parVolume))
        prob += vol
        print(vol)
        #print(t)

# constraints
    t = vol >= 1
    print(t)
    prob += t


  I changed the code to this format and I get a warning: UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective. Still the output remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I haven't checked your full problem formulation, but I think you're objective function at least is wrong. My understanding is that the objective should be the No. of containers which are used:

```
# Objective - minimise wasted volume = volume of chosen boxes - volume of parcels
    prob += lpSum([us[i] * parcel.conVolume[i] for i in range(parcel.containers)]) - sum(parcel.parVolume)
```

If I make the change above the output I get is:

```
('Status:', 'Optimal')
('Objective value:', 45.0)

The values of the variables : 

('p11', '=', 1.0)
('p12', '=', 0.0)
('p21', '=', 1.0)
('p22', '=', 0.0)
('p31', '=', 1.0)
('p32', '=', 0.0)
('u1', '=', 1.0)
('u2', '=', 0.0)
```

So at least the objective is working now - and it seems to have solved the packing problem using just one of the containers assuming all of the constraints are set right (I haven't checked them).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't want to optimise the number of containers. I am looking to minimize the unused volume in the container. How do I do that?

Comment: Have changed the answer to minimise the wasted space - this is just a case of weighting the variables of whether each box is used by the amount of volume in it - as the volume of the parcels which all have to be include is fixed - see revised answer.

Comment: Thank you it works! Is there a difference between Ipsum and sum? for all the other constraints I have used just sum. Also, can you help me on how to write the coordinates to check the overlapping and dimension constraint? I am unable to figure out. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's customary to accept the answer and/or upvote if it answers your question and is useful. Do you have a link to the full formulation you are trying to implement? All of the separate images to bits of the formulation are hard to follow.

Comment: Hi, apologies I didn't know I had to accept the answer. The upvote is not publicly displaced as I have less than 15 reputations. This is the paper I am following - https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/itor.12111. The constraints are from page 7.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with getting the rest of your code working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Highly appreciate. Do you have any ides of how to get the overlapping constraint working?

Comment: Are you able to share a full version of your code, and some example data (parcels and containers), and explain what problem you are having - i.e. how have you tried to implement the constraint and why/how isn't it working?

Comment: I haven't implemented the constraint. I don't know how to.

Comment: Hi @kabdulla, I have shared the full version of my code with the input data. There is no error but the output is not showing the placement sequence. Can you help?